# How to define a JSON object inside a DOM `data` attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I tried to set some `json` data inside a `dataset` attribute.

The `HTML` looks likes this

```
<div data-switch="true" data-json="{'key1': 'value 1'}, {'key2': 'value 2'}">
```

The data inside the `data-json` I obtain it with `JavaScript` in this way:

```
var json = $("[data-json]").data("json").toString();
json = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Whatever I try, it doesn't convert it to an `object`. It just returns a `string`

**With `toString()` and `stringify()`**

```js
$(function() {
 json = $("[data-json]").data("json").toString();
    json = JSON.stringify(json);
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    
    console.log(json);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-json="{'key1': 'value 1'}, {'key2', 'value 2'}">

</div>
```

When i remove the `toString()` and `stringify()` functions, it gives the following error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`

**Without `toString()` and `stringify()`**

```js
$(function() {
 json = $("[data-json]").data("json");
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    
    console.log(json);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-json="{'key1': 'value 1'}, {'key2', 'value 2'}">

</div>
```

**Fiddle with original `JavaScript` and `HTML`**

```js
/**
 * Switch content inside Metro UI blocks
 *
 * @requires {data-switch}   Set data-switch="true" inside the dom
 */
$(function() {
 
 /**
  * Get all switch elements
  */
 var switches = $("[data-switch]");
 /**
  * Sample data for each switch element  
 var switches_data = {
  0: {
   0: {
    image: 'https://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rules-good-ui-design-web-project-thumbnail.png',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
   },
   1: {
    image: 'http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/Images/28618-workplace-manager580x224_tcm21-1830661.jpg',
    content: 'Aliquam interdum sit amet nibh aliquet accumsan.'
   },
   2: {
    image: 'http://cdn.moneycrashers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/manager2.jpg',
    content: 'Vestibulum sed metus eu justo sagittis congue.'
   }
  },
  1: {
   0: {
    image: 'https://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rules-good-ui-design-web-project-thumbnail.png',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
   },
   1: {
    image: 'http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/Images/28618-workplace-manager580x224_tcm21-1830661.jpg',
    content: 'Aliquam interdum sit amet nibh aliquet accumsan.'
   },
   2: {
    image: 'http://cdn.moneycrashers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/manager2.jpg',
    content: 'Vestibulum sed metus eu justo sagittis congue.'
   }
  },
  2: {
   0: {
    image: 'https://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rules-good-ui-design-web-project-thumbnail.png',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
   },
   1: {
    image: 'http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/Images/28618-workplace-manager580x224_tcm21-1830661.jpg',
    content: 'Aliquam interdum sit amet nibh aliquet accumsan.'
   },
   2: {
    image: 'http://cdn.moneycrashers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/manager2.jpg',
    content: 'Vestibulum sed metus eu justo sagittis congue.'
   }
  }
 };
 */
 /**
  * Check if elements exists
  */
 if(switches.length > 0) {
  /**
   * Loop through objects
   *
   * @var c  Object Key
   * @var e  Object Value
   */
  $.each(switches, function(c, e) {
   /** 
    * Get switches data current object
    */
   var switches_data = $(this).data("switches");
   console.log(switches_data);
   /**
    * Get next div
    */
   var next = $(this).children().first()[0];
   next = $(next);
   /**
    * Set type animation
    */
   var animation = "flipInX";
   /**
    * Set index where to start from
    */
   var index = 0;
   /**
    * Generate interval seconds, a random number so they will never be the same
    */
   var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6000) + 3000);
   /**
    * Loop through switches
    *
    * @var i  Object Key
    * @var b Object Value
    */
   $.each(switches_data, function(i, b) {
    /**
      * Create new element for each switches
      */
    var el = $("<div />").attr({class: "metro-ui-column-content animated", id: "content-column-" + i});
    /**
     * Append el to next element, previous defined
     */
    el.appendTo(next);
    /**
     * Set background image for el
     */
    el.css({
     "background": "url("+ b.image +") no-repeat",
     "background-size": "cover"
    });
    /**
     * Append html content
     */
    el.html( "<div class=\"metro-ui-column-html\">" + b.content + "</div>");
   });
   
   /**
    * Set static this
    */
   var self = $(this);
   /**
    * Find all animated object
    */
   var animated = $(this).find(".animated");
   /**
    * Generate random number between 2000 and 4000, it acts as seconds for interval
    */
   var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8000) + 4000);
   /**
    * Loop through animated objects
    *
    * @var i Object Key
    * @var e Object Value
    */
   $.each(animated, function(i, e) {
    /**
     * Start with the first animated object in the current loop
     */ 
    if(i === 0) {
     /**
      * Start with an timeout with random generated content, so no content will ever be loaded at the same time
      */
     setTimeout(function() {
      /**
        * Gets visible by setting the z-index
        */
      $(e).css("z-index", 2).addClass("flipInX");
     }, x);
    }    
   });
   /**
    * Set new index higher than first object
    */
   var index = 3 ;
   /**
    * Set interval function to start looping the animation
    */
   setInterval(function() {
    /**
     * Get next object from current object
     */
    var next = self.find(".flipInX").next();
    /**
     * If there is no next object reset to first object
     */
    if(next.length === 0) {
     /**
      * Update next to first object cause next doenst exist
      */
     var next = self.find(".animated").first();
    }
    /**
     * Set new index and add animation class
     */
    next.css("z-index", index++).addClass("flipInX").siblings().removeClass("flipInX");
   }, x);
  });
 }
 
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700');
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Metro theme UI */
.metro-theme-ui {
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 250px;
}
.metro-ui-row {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  /* Fix breaking when height is 0 */
}
.metro-ui-row:after,
.metro-ui-row:before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}
.metro-ui-column {
  position: relative;
  background: #12A7CC;
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.metro-ui-column.fadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn .33s ease;
}
.metro-ui-column.fadeOut {
  animation: fadeOut .33s ease;
}
.metro-ui-column .metro-ui-column-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.metro-ui-column .metro-ui-column-html {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* Calculate column width */
.metro-ui-col {
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}
.metro-ui-col-10 {
  width: calc(100%);
}
.metro-ui-col-9 {
  width: calc(11.11111111%);
}
.metro-ui-col-8 {
  width: calc(12.5%);
}
.metro-ui-col-7 {
  width: calc(14.28571429%);
}
.metro-ui-col-6 {
  width: calc(16.66666667%);
}
.metro-ui-col-5 {
  width: calc(20%);
}
.metro-ui-col-4 {
  width: calc(25%);
}
.metro-ui-col-3 {
  width: calc(33.33333333%);
}
.metro-ui-col-2 {
  width: calc(50%);
}
.metro-ui-col-1 {
  width: calc(100%);
}
/* Keyframes */
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.animated.flipOutX,
.animated.flipOutY,
.animated.bounceIn,
.animated.bounceOut {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}
@keyframes flipInX {
  from {
    left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}
.metro-ui-column .metro-ui-column-content.flipInX {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
}
@keyframes flipOutX {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.flipOutX {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipOutX;
  animation-name: flipOutX;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="metro-theme-ui">
 <div class="metro-ui-row">
  <div class="metro-ui-col metro-ui-col-10">
   <div class="metro-ui-column"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="metro-ui-row">
  <div class="metro-ui-col metro-ui-col-3" data-switch="true" data-switches='{"image": "https://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/rules-good-ui-design-web-project-thumbnail.png", "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."}, { "image": "http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/Images/28618-workplace-manager580x224_tcm21-1830661.jpg", "content": "Aliquam interdum sit amet nibh aliquet accumsan."}, { "image": "http://cdn.moneycrashers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/manager2.jpg", "content": "Vestibulum sed metus eu justo sagittis congue." }'">
   <div class="metro-ui-column"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="metro-ui-col metro-ui-col-3">
   <div class="metro-ui-column"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="metro-ui-col metro-ui-col-3">
   <div class="metro-ui-column"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="metro-ui-row">
  <div class="metro-ui-col metro-ui-col-3">
   <div class="metro-ui-column"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="metro-ui-col metro-ui-col-3">
   <div class="metro-ui-column"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="metro-ui-col metro-ui-col-3">
   <div class="metro-ui-column"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This json is invalid, is it the actual json you're using (to test) or do you have a real example?

Comment: Also you have a comma after `key2`, whereas it should be a colon `:`

Comment: @LiamMacDonald https://codepen.io/richardmauritz/pen/WjZJOp

Comment: @RichardMauritz add square brackets around your JSON (so encapsulate the 3 objects in to an array)

Comment: @rishipuri Sorry, that was a type. Anyway, `[]` around it did the job. Thanks guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually just pass a valid json object it should just work.

```js
json = $("[data-json]").data("json");

console.log(typeof(json))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-switch="true" data-json='[{"key1": "value 1"}, {"key2": "value 2"}]'>
```

Comment: I agree this is the issue. I'd suggest the poster uses a JSON validator to check in future - it's easy to miss simple things! https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Thank you sir, just adding brackets `[]` did the job ;)

Comment: Well spotted, I should have used the OP's JSON in my examples, I would have noticed... :-)

Comment: Thank you. This answer helped me. My problem was to use `data-json='@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.PairValidationDropdown))'` - solution was using single `'` quote insted of double `"` for data-json attribute it self. P.S. `@Html.Raw` added automaticly the `[]` for json.

Answer (score 6):

You use valid JSON (which requires that you use double quotes, not single quotes, around keys and other strings). Then either retrieve with [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and parse with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), or if you want to use jQuery's data store, use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to load it into that store and access it; `data` will parse it automatically. Note that `data` is **not** just an accessor for `data-8` attributes, it's both more and less than that, so be sure to read the API docs for it and use it if you want its features, and don't use it if you don't.

Example:

```js
var d = $("div[data-json]");
// Using `attr` and `JSON.parse`:
console.log(JSON.parse(d.attr("data-json")));
// Using jQuery'd data store
console.log(d.data("json"));
```

```html
<div data-json='{"answer":42,"question":"Life, the Universe, and Everything!"}'></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the attribute uses single quotes, so we can conveniently use double quotes in the JSON. But that would fail if we used `'` in the JSON anywhere (such as in a string: `"where":"Joe's house"`).

The text of attributes is HTML, not raw text. So if you're generating this JSON dynamically, perhaps in a server-side template or something, be sure that when it's output, it's output as HTML text, not raw text, to ensure that any necessary encoding is done. When you do that, the quotes may well be turned into `&quot;` entities, in which case there's no problem using `"` around the attribute value:

```js
var d = $("div[data-json]");
// Using `attr` and `JSON.parse`:
console.log(JSON.parse(d.attr("data-json")));
// Using jQuery'd data store
console.log(d.data("json"));
```

```html
<div data-json="{&quot;answer&quot;:42,&quot;question&quot;:&quot;Life, the Universe, and Everything!&quot;}"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried to use double quotes, however i keep getting the same error. <-- nvm, you just wrote one ;)

Comment: @RichardMauritz: Added an example.

Comment: Can you check out this https://codepen.io/richardmauritz/pen/WjZJOp? I can't get it working. I tried to do double quotes

Comment: @RichardMauritz: I wondered if you might be having quotes problems and added a note to the above. Re CodePen: The full content of your question must be *in* your question, not just linked. (And it would need to be a [mcve], rather than the full thing.)

Comment: I just had to add `[]` arround it, like @rishipuri awnsered. It worked. Thanks anyway for your explanation.

Comment: @RichardMauritz: Well, I **did** mention valid JSON. :-) I just didn't notice you were listing a bunch of objects with no surrounding structure.

Comment: Thats why i upvoted your awnser, because it was correct information. But the accepted awnser was the simplest one for me ;)

Comment: @RichardMauritz: Absolutely. :-)